# T-SQL Update data query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to update some records here are the table structures

Table A is the main one we need to update some records
    A(Id,DataYear0,DataYear1,DataYear3)

Table B has some other than data that we require
    B(Id,Year,DataYear)

Example data for Table B:
    B(abc,1950,1.25)
    B(abc,1951,1.29)
    ..
    ..
    B(abc,2008,1.67)
    B(abc,2009,1.23)
    B(abc,2010,1.52)
    B(abc,2011,1.78)
    B(abc,2012,NULL)

With 2012 as the current Year, I need to update the data values of the previous three years(i.e, 2011,2010,2009) in Table A

So, table A needs to be updated as A(abc,1.78,1.52,1.23) for the above example. Similarly other records need to be updated.

Id is the primary key on both tables.

The query I have so far is

```
UPDATE A SET
    DataYear0 = CASE WHEN Year+1 = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN DataYear END,
    DataYear1 = CASE WHEN Year+2 = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN DataYear END,
    DataYear2 = CASE WHEN Year+3 = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN DataYear END
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.Id=B.Id
```

This did not work, because I think it is returning extra year records apart from the years that we want i.e., just the last three years

```
UPDATE A SET
   DataYear0 = CASE WHEN Year+1 = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN DataYear END,
   DataYear1 = CASE WHEN Year+2 = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN DataYear END,
DataYear2 = CASE WHEN Year+3 = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN DataYear END
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.Id=B.Id
GROUP BY Id,Year,DataYear
HAVING ((YEAR(GETDATE())-3) <= Year) AND (Year <> YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

But still the data is not being updated.

Tried using CTE

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT 
    A.Id
    ,B.Year
    ,B.DataYear 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Year DESC) as row
 FROM A
 LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.Id=B.Id
 GROUP BY Id,Year,DataYear
 HAVING ((YEAR(GETDATE())-3) <= Year) AND (Year <> YEAR(GETDATE()))
 )


UPDATE
    A.DataYear0 = CASE WHEN row=1 THEN DataYear END
    ,A.DataYear1 = CASE WHEN row=2 THEN DataYear END
    ,A.DataYear2 = CASE WHEN row=3 THEN DataYear END
FROM A
LEFT JOIN cte
    ON A.Id = cte.Id
```

The data is still not updated. I would appreciate any suggestions that anyone might have. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Id is not the Primary Key in table B (it's not unique).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE a
    SET DataYear0 = COALESCE(d0.DataYear,DataYear0),
        DataYear1 = COALESCE(d1.DataYear,DataYear1),
        DataYear2 = COALESCE(d2.DataYear,DataYear2)
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B d0 ON d0.Id = a.Id and d0.[Year] = YEAR(GETDATE())-1
LEFT JOIN B d1 ON d1.Id = a.Id and d1.[Year] = YEAR(GETDATE())-2
LEFT JOIN B d2 ON d2.Id = a.Id and d2.[Year] = YEAR(GETDATE())-3
```

Comment: `COALESCE()` with the original value may not be the right value for missing years. Of course it's a little hard to speculate with the limited info we have.

Comment: Exactly.  I was guessing that we didn't want to change it to NULL if there was no row, but it's easy to replace them with just d0.DataYear, d1.DataYear, d2.DataYear if that's not the case.

Comment: I am mesmerized at the brilliant simplicity. It works! Although the other suggested answers work, I used this as my answer as it integrated better with the other code I have. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises from an attempt to update single row from multiple rows. To see it, convert your updates to selects. In such a situation last updater wins, leaving other two columns as nulls. To solve, use subqueries or some way to transform rows to columns, like pivot.

Now, the fun of overengineering:

```
update A
set DataYear0 = pvt.[0],
    DataYear1 = pvt.[1],
    DataYear2 = pvt.[2]
from A
inner join
(
  select u.ID, u.[0], u.[1], u.[2]
  from
  (
    select b.id,
           3 - (year(getdate()) - b.Year) YearOffset,
           b.DataYear
      from B
     where b.Year >= year(getdate()) - 3
       and b.Year < year(getdate())
  ) p
  pivot (min(DataYear) 
         for YearOffset in ([0], [1], [2])
  ) u
) pvt
 on A.id = pvt.id;
```

[You may see this query in action @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0fc3/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE A
SET
    DataYear0 = (SELECT DataYear FROM B WHERE A.id = B.id AND Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1),
    DataYear1 = (SELECT DataYear FROM B WHERE A.id = B.id AND Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2),
    DataYear2 = (SELECT DataYear FROM B WHERE A.id = B.id AND Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 3)
```

The `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` is not standard SQL. This approach seems a little verbose but it's the proper way and the optimizer can still handle it effectively.

It would also cause an error if any of the subqueries was not a scalar result and that is a good thing. The others answers would allow that to slip by.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and the explanation. It works! Many thanks once again.